# Tcl switch statement and -regexp quoting?

Tags: regex, tcl, quoting

There must be an extra level of evaluation when using the Tcl switch command.  Here's an example session at the repl to show what I mean:

```
$ tclsh
% regexp {^\s*foo} " foo"
1
% regexp {^\\s*foo} " foo"
0
% switch -regexp " foo" {^\\s*foo {puts "match"}}
match
% switch -regexp " foo" {{^\s*foo} {puts "match"}}
match
```

...There needed to be an extra backslash added inside the first "switch" version.  This is consistent between 8.5.0 and 8.6.0 on Windows.  Can someone point me to the section of the manual where this and similar instances of extra levels of unquoting are described?  My first thought was that the curly brackets in the first "switch" version would have protected the backslash, but "switch" itself must be applying an extra level of backslash susbtitution to the patterns.  Unless I'm misunderstanding the nuances of something else.

**Edit:**
  ...hmmm...  Like Johannes Kuhn says below backslash substitution apparently depends on the dynamic context of use, and not the lexical context of creation...

```
% set t {\s*foo}
\s*foo
% proc test_s x {set x}
% test_s $t
\s*foo
% proc test_l x {lindex $x 0}
% test_l $t
s*foo
% puts $t
^\s*foo
```

...that seems to be quite the interesting design choice.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you describe here is simple to solve:

The difference between `switch` and `regexp` is that switch takes actually a list.
So if we print the first element of the list `{^\s*foo {puts "match"}}` with

```
% puts [lindex {^\s*foo {puts "match"}} 0]
^s*foo
```

it results in something that we don't want.

List constructing is a [little bit complex](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/407.html), if you are not sure, use an interactive Tcl shell that constructs one for you with `list`.

**Edit**: Indeed, it is an intresting desin choice, but this applies to everything in Tcl. For example `expr` uses an minilanguage designed for arithmetic expressions. It is up to the command what it shall do with it's arguments. Even language constucts like `if`, `for`, `while` are just commands that treats one of the arguments as expression, and the other arguments as script. This design makes it possible to create new control structures, like sqlite's eval, which takes the SQL statment and a script that it should evaluate for each result.

Comment: +1 Didn't know that `switch` actually takes a list. Makes sense!

Comment: The [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/440) also has more good edge case examples dealing with lists.